# Is a delay expected when cancelling a request with axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, axios

I'm making a live search function in VueJS, while it has debounce, sometimes the user can start typing when request just has been send.

I'm already cancelling old request with the cancel token provided by Axios but I noticed that the last request just takes too long

```
let search_cancel;

...

if(search_cancel != undefined){
    console.log("Request cancelled")
    search_cancel()
}


try {
    const URL = 'home/producto?descripcion=' + description
    const { data } = await axios.get(URL, {
        cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
            // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
            search_cancel = c;
        })
    })
}catch...
```

Here is a pic about what I'm referring:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzsQK.png

the search doesn't take that long the first time, it seems that it waits for each cancelled request

Comment: _it seems that it waits for each cancelled request_ Are you sure?  The waterfall doesn't bear that out.  More likely is that, although the request is cancelled on the _browser/client_, the _server_ is still processing all those requests and _that_ is what is causing the delay...

Comment: I thought of that as well, but to be frank I didn't (still) know if it is really the server (Laravel)